# can not upload file through formdata in angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am using angular to upload an image as shown in the code below.

The file data is retrieved from this.formGroup.value, however the issue is when this file data is passed to formData, it is found formData is still empty, thus unable to send through http request. I don't know how to solve this problem. any idea or other way?

```
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", this.formGroup.value);
    console.log(formData);
    this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/api/users/picture',formData);
```

The whole code is shown below.

```
<form action="uploadUrl" [formGroup]="formGroup" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <input type="file" name="avatar" />
         <button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid || formGroup.prestine">Submit</button>
```

```
  onSubmit(){
    console.log('onSubmit',this.formGroup.value);
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", this.formGroup.value);

    console.log(formData);   // the formData is empty


    this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/api/users/picture',formData); 
      .subscribe( res => {
          console.log(res);
      }, error => {
        console.log('changePicture error',error);
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i do this like :

Template :

```
<input formControlName="picture" 
        (change)="onFileChange($event)"
        class="form-control" 
        type="file" 
        id="picture" 
        name="picture">
```

Components :

```
onFileChange(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  this.formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);
   this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/api/users/picture',this.formData); 
  .subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res);
  }, error => {
    console.log('changePicture error',error);
  });
```

}

And i add header to my http request to allow form data:

```
headersConfig['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

Comment: const file = event.target.files[0];
      let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);
    console.log(formData );                but formData is still showing :   FormData {} , why is that

Comment: this is normal behaviour, just send it like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have a trig as the same , but i run it :

```
//--------------
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,

};

fetch('your-upload-url', options);
```